Convergence of Numerical Methods for Singular Data
Suppose I'm interested in numerically solving a differential equation with a singular source term, say,
$$
\nabla^2u = \delta(\mathbf{x}) \quad \mathrm{on} \; \Omega \tag{1}
\\
u = 0 \quad \mathrm{on} \; \partial\Omega
$$
with the finite element method. I know that, given $\nabla^2u = f$ where $f \in L^2(\Omega)$, then the associated variational problem
$$
a(u_h,v) = (f,v)
$$
has a unique solution $u_h$ in some appropriate function space (here I'm being quite cavalier with my notation, you'll have to forgive me). However, if the requirement that $f \in L^2(\Omega)$ is relaxed (as in (1)), under what conditions can I expect the finite element method to converge to the analytical solution?

If your discretization is randomly generated (with $h\to 0$), then probably you cannot get any guarantee, since you can choose where the point source located in the element (on nodes or not on nodes), which will generate very random result. Usually, you need to use a smooth-out point source to compute, that can give an estimate of error.
